# How schema markup can be helpful for mobile app website?

Tags: data-structures, schema, google-local-search

I want to implement schema markup for a mobile app website. I read schema.org/MobileApplication, but there are lot of properties. I am not getting which property are useful to give more effective output for local search?

Answer (score 1):

The schema is important to every website page. Do not confuse, use a required property to your mobile application website.

Answer (score 0):

Schema markup allows search engine to analyze vast information in shortcut method. For Mobile app website you would like to use properties like- downloadUrl, countriesSupported, fileSize, about, author, description and image.

Answer (score 0):

data-structures schema google-local-search

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">
  <span itemprop="name">Angry Birds</span> -

  REQUIRES <span itemprop="operatingSystem">ANDROID</span>
  <link itemprop="applicationCategory" href="http://schema.org/GameApplication"/>

  RATING:
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.6</span> (
    <span itemprop="ratingCount">8864</span> ratings )
  </div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    Price: $<span itemprop="price">1.00</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer could really do with some more explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.